# Passportjs sessions fail when JSON response is set first

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using express + passport to handle authentication for a react app. Because I'm using react, I don't want to automatically redirect the login request via express, instead I want to return JSON.

However, I've noticed that simply returning JSON and then calling `next(null, user)` seems to prevent passport from running the `serializeUser` method. By calling `next` passport should automatically call the `req.login` function, which doesn't appear to happen when I've sent json.

It appears that if I manually call `req.login` and *then* send the JSON, it works (the serialize method is called, the user has a session).

Is there a way to send a json response and call `next` without having to manually invoke req.login? Feels like I'm just not doing things the correct way.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ errorMessage: err.message });

                return next(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                res.json({ errorMessage: 'Invalid user.' });

                return next(err);
            }

            // This fails to invoke the session serialization:
            // res.json({
            //     success: true,
            //     username: user.username
            // });

            // return next(null, user);

            // This works:
            req.logIn(user, loginErr => {
                if (loginErr) {
                    return next(loginErr);
                }

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    username: user.username
                });

                return;
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
};
```